# modifiy securesocial.appName in play framework 2.2.x

Tags: securesocial

I tried to change the securesocial name in both Build.scala and SecuredSocial.conf but none worked. Is there a way to change it so the line below shows the modified app name?

```
<span class="brand" >@Messages("securesocial.appName")</span>
```

Build.scala

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build{
    val appName         = "New App Name"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"
    ...
}
```

SecuredSocial.conf

```
securesocial {
    appName = "Test Name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Messages` renders values from a language property file. Put it in `conf/messages`:

```
securesocial.appName=Desired value
```